# How to submit a form html with Dart?

Tags: html, flutter, dart

I need to scrape some data for the Dart / Flutter application and I need to log in to access the page.

How do I submit changes to the form data and click on the login button? I tried as follows:

```
    var loginPage = await http.get('https://mypage.com/login');
    var document = parse(loginPage.body);
    var username = document.querySelector('#username') as InputElement;
    var password = document.querySelector('#password') as InputElement;
    username.value = 'USERNAME';
    password.value = 'PASSWORD';
    var submit = document.querySelector('.btn-submit') as ButtonElement;
    submit.click();
```

But I have the following error:

```
Error: 'InputElement' isn't a type.
Error: 'ButtonElement' isn't a type.
```

I also tried the following:

```
InputElement username = document.querySelector('#username');
```

But a get the error `A value of type 'Element' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'InputElement'`

I need to make this scrape in the flutter application to avoid passing the password using API.

How can I log in to the page to get the data?

Comment: did you the solution I am looking for same for integrating Cybersource payment gateway sending html form.

Answer (score -1):

`InputElement` and `ButtonElement` are part of the `dart:html` package, therefore, we shouldn't forget to import it in our code:

```
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;


void submitForm() async {
  var loginPage = await http.get('https://mypage.com/login');
  var document = parse(loginPage.body);
  var username = document.querySelector('#username') as InputElement;
  var password = document.querySelector('#password') as InputElement;
  username.value = 'USERNAME';
  password.value = 'PASSWORD';
  var submit = document.querySelector('.btn-submit') as ButtonElement;
  submit.click();
}
```

By doing so, the compiler will recognize `InputElement` and `ButtonElement` as correct types.

Another, more elegant, way to obtain the same result would be:

```
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void submitForm() async {
   var loginPage = await http.get('https://mypage.com/login');
   Document document = parse(loginPage.body);
   (document.querySelector('#username') as InputElement).value = 'USERNAME';
   (document.querySelector('#password') as InputElement).value = 'PASSWORD';
   (document.querySelector('.btn-submit') as ButtonElement).click();
}
```

If we'd like to use the same functionality in a Flutter project, we might need the help of the `universal_html` package:

1. Add this to your package's pubspec.yaml file:

```
dependencies:
  universal_html: ^1.2.3
```

2. Run `flutter pub get`
3. Import the package and use the code:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:universal_html/html.dart';

void submitForm() async {
   var loginPage = await http.get('https://mypage.com/login');
   Document document = parse(loginPage.body);
   (document.querySelector('#username') as InputElement).value = 'USERNAME';
   (document.querySelector('#password') as InputElement).value = 'PASSWORD';
   (document.querySelector('.btn-submit') as ButtonElement).click();
}
```

Comment: That way I get the error ```The prefix 'document' can't be used here because it is shadowed by a local declaration.``` in ```as document.InputElement```.

Comment: Code has been edited to address the issue

Comment: Now I get the error ```Error: Not found: 'dart:html'```. I am running on an Android emulator.

Comment: `universal_html` package can be used for cross-platform support. I've updated the answer to include this scenario as well.

Comment: ```universal_html``` fixed this, but is still giving the following error: ```Unhandled Exception: type 'Element' is not a subtype of type 'InputElement' in type cast```